# Split string by words in R

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

I would like to split a string by two words:

```
s <- "PCB153 treated HepG2 cells at T18"
strsplit(s, split = <treated><at>)
```

What should I write instead of <>?

I would get:

```
"PCB153" "HepG2 cells" "T18"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
strsplit(s, split="treated|at")
#[[1]]
#[1] "PCB153 "       " HepG2 cells " " T18"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to enter it as a string. To split on treated:

```
s <- "PCB153 treated HepG2 cells at T18"
s2 <- strsplit(s,split="treated")
unlist(s2)
```

To split on treated and at:

```
unlist(strsplit(unlist(s2),split="at"))
```

Comment: I would like to get it in three by two words.